# Construct confidence interval for price per area, from weighted average price for quantity, and weighted average quantity per area

Tags: confidence-interval, econometrics, weighted-mean

I have function for obtaining the weighted mean for price per quantity, where $p$ is price, and $w$ is the weight, for some product $i$.

$$\bar p_a = \sum p_{i} w_{i}$$

and a quantity per area,  where $q$ is quantity, and $w$ is the weight, for some conditional probability weight for measuring the within area distribution $j$

$$\bar q = \sum q_{j} w_{j}$$

And want to find the price for unit area, which is the product of the price in the area, and mean quantity in the area.

$$\hat P = \Big(\sum p_{i} w_{i}\Big) \Big(\sum q_{j} w_{j}\Big)$$

How can i construct confidence intervals for $\hat P$?

---

Edit: The intuition is that for 1 unit area ($km^2$) i have a distribution of timber quantities $m^3$ distributed across several different species, qualities etc. In the same area i know the mean price for each product provided from harvesting (different types of sorting of the timber), for one unit ($m^3$) of timber, however i cannot observe the product distribution from the observed quantities. Now, product of the weighted average price for one unit of quantity, and the weighted average quantity per area unit, will be the average price per unit area. Now, the average $\hat P$ fits the control area, however, i would like to construct confidence intervals for the mean.

Comment: "Price per area" would suggest you want to *divide* rather than multiply as shown in the final formula.  Did you perhaps forget to insert a "$/$"?

Comment: I can see how the formulation is unclear, added a description of the problem, and clarified the question.